# Javascript not working in Ajax Page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I Want to Show the datepicker in 2 input form when i hit on OK button another input from will be load,but here my datapicker is not working .My DatePicker is Not Working when it load from ajax page.
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
      <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
<script>
var xyz;
function ShowAjax()
{
    xyz=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xyz.onreadystatechange=AjaxShow
    var url="AjaxPage.html";
    xyz.open("GET",url,true);
    xyz.send();
    function AjaxShow()
    {
        if(xyz.readyState==4 || xyz.readyState=="complete")
            {
            document.getElementById('Mylocation').innerHTML=xyz.responseText
            }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table> 
<tr> <td> <input type="text"  name="uname" id="datepicker"></td></tr>
<tr> <td id="Mylocation"></td></tr>
<tr> <td><input type="button"    value="OK"   onclick="ShowAjax();"/> </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is My AjaxPage.html"

```
<td><input type="text" name="test"  id="datepicker1"></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

call your date picker after your ajax request completed.

```
if(xyz.readyState==4 || xyz.readyState=="complete){ 
    document.getElementById('Mylocation').innerHTML=xyz.responseText;
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome!! it was not working because you called datepicker() even before input element was not available on page. element gets added after ajax get finished.

Answer (score 1):

`$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();` finds the element and turns it into a date picker. You run that code when the document is ready.

Later on, you click the button and add the element with `id=datepicker1` to the page.

This is **after** you have run `$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();`.

You need to move it so it runs when the element exists.

i.e. after `document.getElementById('Mylocation').innerHTML=xyz.responseText`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery like that :

```
function ShowAjax() {
    $.get( "AjaxPage.html", function( data ) {
        $( "#Mylocation" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

or :

```
function ShowAjax() {
    $.get( "AjaxPage.html", function( data ) {
        $( "#Mylocation" ).html( data );
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    });
}
```